# Need to create a custom query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to clear out invalid users created by a scipted attack from the database.

The query would:

check if row name "about:me" contains "michael kors"

if yes, then set row "account_status" to "inactive"

I'm a very novice "DBA" so I'm hoping an example of a correct query in this case will help me to be able to construct others and help other users do the same.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you provide your table structure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column name is really `about:me` (a colon would be unusual), and `account_status` is actually a text field (not an integer *indicating* active/inactive), and imagining your table is named `users` (you didn't say), something like this would work:

```
update users
set account_status = 'inactive'
where `about:me` like '%michael kors%';
```

The backticks allow unusual characters like `:` to appear in the column name; the `%` allows varying whitespace (or other random characters) around the name when used with `like`; the `like` also allows us to match regardless of upper/lowercase in the name column.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I can use this as a template to build other queries now which was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Here's a follow up query I keep running into errors with: The table name is 'signup' and I need to find all rows where email_verified = no and watched_videos = 0 and delete them.

Comment: `delete from signup where email_verified = 'no' and watched_videos = 0`

Comment: You were correct, the actual column name is 'aboutme', it shows with a colon in a different view using my Mac SQL client.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're describing a table 'tbl' with fields 'about:me' and 'account_status', you should be able to run an UPDATE with a WHERE to do this.  Something like...

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET account_status = 'inactive' 
WHERE `about:me` LIKE '%michael kors%';
```

Note this uses `LIKE` which means it's case insensitive and uses the wildcard character `%` to match anything containing `michael kors`.

Hope it helps!